# Jquery Datepicker with Done and Clear Buttons

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery Datepicker. I am using MM-yy format(textbox disable state). In date picker either **Done or Clear** any one button is working. **I want to show both Done and Clear buttons are in Active state in date picker**.

Please check the pictures

[image]
[image]

Please help me to solved this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are referring to the fact that the "Today" button is greyed out.

In order to avoid that you will have to override the .css

Simpy add the following to your .css file i.e.

```
.ui-datepicker div.ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 1;
}
```